# No se definen los valores recibidos - Notice: Undefined index: contrasena1, contrasena2, rut,... etc

Tags: php

Antes que nada darle las gracias a César Alejandro M, por la ayuda que me brindó. Pero el problema sigue. Me pueden orientar donde más seguir buscando???. Muchas gracias desde ya.

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

 if(isset($_POST['contrasena1'])&&($_POST['contrasena2'])&& isset($_POST['rut'])
     && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido']) && isset($_POST['cargo']) && isset($_POST['contrasena2'])){ 


if($_POST['contrasena1']==$_POST['contrasena2']) {
        $rut=$_POST['rut'];
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
        $cargo=$_POST['cargo'];
        $contraseña=md5($_POST['contrasena2']);

        $consulta="INSERT INTO personal(rut, nombre, apellido, cargo, contraseña) VALUES ('$rut', '$nombre', '$apellido', '$cargo', '$contraseña')";

        $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("No se pudo crear el registro");

        header("Location:formulario.php?valida=si");
}else {
    header("Location:formulario.php?errornea=si");
}
     }else{
         echo "Faltan datos para procesar el formulario"; 
     }
?>
```

Conexion exitosa
Base de Datos encontrada

Notice: Undefined index: contrasena1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Taller_PHP\Sesion 5\registro.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: contrasena2 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Taller_PHP\Sesion 5\registro.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: rut in D:\xampp\htdocs\Taller_PHP\Sesion 5\registro.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: nombre in D:\xampp\htdocs\Taller_PHP\Sesion 5\registro.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: apellido in D:\xampp\htdocs\Taller_PHP\Sesion 5\registro.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: email in D:\xampp\htdocs\Taller_PHP\Sesion 5\registro.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: contrasena2 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Taller_PHP\Sesion 5\registro.php on line 10
No se pudo crear el registro

El error es que no encuentra los datos en $_POST. Donde mas puedo seguir buscando???. Como puedo ver o donde almacena los datos $_POST???. Desde ya infinitas gracias, y perdón por que en la pregunta anterior, no me dí cuenta de que na había salido el listado.`introducir el código aquí`

Comment: En la linea antes del if podrias hacer un print_r($_POST) para que imprima el array del POST y ver si esta vacio

Comment: Estas seguro que estas haciendo POST en tu formulario y no un GET?

Comment: Falta el código de tu html donde llamas a este php y el código de conexion.php

Comment: pon el código de como envías los datos(formulario html, ajax, etc) para ver como llegan, al parecer no están llegando bien estos datos.... también el ultimo error que te sale se debe a que te falta un isset en contraseña2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta parte del código:

```
if(isset($_POST['contrasena1'])&&($_POST['contrasena2'])&& isset($_POST['rut'])
     && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido']) && isset($_POST['cargo']) && isset($_POST['contrasena2'])){
```

Veo que falta un `isset` en `$_POST['contrasena2']`. Eso ya lo modificaste?